# DC Power supply fallback

Tags: power-supply

Looking for pre made material that I can buy or a diagram on how I can have one power supply as backup (fallback) for 8 power supply on DC. Example: If one of the 8 power supply fails, the backup power supply will take over.

When a Power supply go down, I receive a notification, but it can take days before a technician get to site. Having one power supply backup for each power supply cost too much.

Thanks!

Comment: @Stiddily That's an answer, not just a comment. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whats called N+1 redundancy. This will be the simplest solution if you're going to have 9 power supplies connected anyway.

With 8 power supplies, say they have a maximum current of 50A. Your load is 400A. If you instead power that load with 9 supplies, each will be putting out 44A. If one of these supplies were to fail, the units would now be putting out 50A each. If the load is fairly constant, you can trigger your notification off of the increase in current from each supply.

Comment: Ok Thanks! So i have one power supply per load, If I understand correctly, the following diagram should work. [Diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tleVu5agW3ORUfY6es6Gdnx_-QbJIa7T/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Seems it. If that diagram is accurate, you have each of the loads in parallel, so to the supplies it just seems like 1 big load.

Comment: I See… Right. I’m probably wrong, but I have 2 concerns with this approach. 1) With 9 power supply of 300W I have the possibility of generating a total of 2700W. If there’s a short in the circuit, would this not be a bigger risk of hazard? 2. If I have 2 power supply down, would this over load and damage the remaining ones?

Comment: @marcb That depends on your power supply. Do you have a datasheet?

Comment: Thanks for the support, i did check with my UL rep and this technic will be acceptable for my project.